# Finding right component package in Multisim

Tags: pcb-design, components, packages, multisim

I have started using Multisim.

I designed a 5V regulator and it works in simulation, now I want to export it to UtilBoard but I can not find the right package or footprint for my component as there are thousands of them in the database.

What I am looking for is common 1/4 Watt resistors, a pair of 100µF and 10µF electrolytic caps and one 0.1µF ceramic capacitor.

I only succeeded finding the right package for K317 regulator which happens to be TO220 package.

What is the best way and best place to look to find a package for the component. For example, how can I find the package type of a normal 1/4Watt resistor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Multisim, but in gEDA the footprints for these kind of components follow a pattern:

```
XXXnnn[n]{P}
```

Where XXX is the type of component, and nnn[n] is the size in mils, and {P} is polarized.

For example:

- ACY400 is a generic 400-mil passive component (such as resistor).
- ALF300 is a 300-mil diode.
- RCY100P is a polarized electrolytic capacitor with 100-mil lead spacing.

(Axx = Axial, Rxx = Radial)

If there is a search facility I would start by narrowing the list down to show just those of the size you are looking for - such as entering "400" for a resistor - then browsing through.  You'll soon get to know what is what - of the thousands of footprints you'll regularly use a mere handful.

Comment: Ok I found some clues in multisim. For the resistor there are lots of options like ackage type:  "RES1300-700X250
Package manufacturer:  IPC-2221A/2222
Pin Count:  2" So is RES1300 reffering to package type? Is it standard or you think it is only used by Multisim? Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like a 1300 mil resistor (quite large - 100 mil is 0.1")

Comment: aaah I was thinking it is millimeters :P hate imperial units...reminds me of imperialism! Thanks.

Comment: Alo found out IPC is the PCB design standard.

Comment: This is why I love Altium. All the components in the libraries have both a compact identifier (as above) **and** a human readable description, and you can search both to find a component.

Answer (score 1):

A little late but for someone hows still looking, like i was....

- Double click on the resistor.
- Go to Value Tab.
- Layout Settings.
- Edit Package.
- List item
- Select package from data Base.
- Look for the right package u want.
- Select and Oks.

For the resistor look for Generic RES0.25.

Comment: Indeed... it's very late!

Comment: Thank you very much. Are there any reference to find all package names of common components like capacitors, variable resistors ?

Answer (score -1):

Here you can fin the answer in details

http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/E81C051F276C5BE0862579E2006975D5

Comment: Link only answers are strongly discouraged.